# Does a HDD/SSD use 1 or 2 device controllers to connect to the OS?

Tags: io, operating-system, hard-drive, solid-state-drive

I am studying Operating Systems, and came across divice controllers.
I gathered that a device controller is hardware whereas a device driver is software.
I also know that a HDD and a SSD both have a small PCB buit into them and I assume those PCB's are the device controllers.
Now what I want to know is if there is another device controller on the PC/motherboard side of the bus/cable connecting the HDD/SSD to the OS?
Is the configuration: OS >> Device Driver >> Bus >> Device Controller >> HDD/SSD
Or is it: OS >> Device Driver >> Device Controler >> Bus >> Device Controller >> HDD/SSD
Or is it some other configuration?

Sites I visited for answers:

- [Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/operating_system/os_io_hardware.htm)
- [JavaPoint](https://www.javatpoint.com/device-driver-vs-device-controller-in-operating-system)
- [Idc online](https://www.idc-online.com/technical_references/pdfs/information_technology/Device_Controllers_Memory_Mapped_and_Port_Mapped.pdf)
- [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-device-driver-and-device-controllers)

Comment: depends on the type of drive and the type of motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

Most hard-disks on desktop are SATA or NVME. eMMC is popular for smartphones but some might use something else. These are hardware interface standards that describe the way to interact electrically with those disks. It tells you what voltage at what frequency and for what amount of time you need to apply (a signal) to a certain pin (a bus line) to make the device behave or react in a certain way.

Most computers are separated in a few external chips. On desktop, it is mostly SATA, NVME, DRAM, USB, Audio Output, network card and graphics card. Even though there is few chips, the CPU would be very expensive if it had to support all those hardware interface standards on the same silicon chip. Instead, the CPU implements PCI/PCI-e as a general interface to interact with all those chips using memory mapped registers. Each of these devices have an external PCI-e controller between the device and the CPU. In the same order as above, you have AHCI, NVME controller, DRAM (not PCI and in the CPU), xHCI (almost everywhere) and Intel HDA (example). Network cards are PCI-e and there isn't really a controller outside the card. Graphics card are also self standing PCI-e devices.

So, the OS detects the registers of those devices that are mapped in the address space. The OS writes at those locations, and it will write the registers of the devices. PCI-e devices can read/write DRAM directly but this is managed by the CPU in its general implementation of the PCI-e standard most likely by doing some bus arbitration. The CPU really doesn't care what's the device that it is writing. It knows that there is a PCI register there and the OS instructs to write it with something so it does. It just happens that this device is an implementation of a standard and that the OS developers read the standard so they write the proper values in those registers and the proper data structures in DRAM to make sure that the device knows what to do.

Drivers implement the standard of the software interface of those controllers. The drivers are the ones instructing the CPU on values to write and writing the proper data structures in DRAM for giving commands to the controllers. The user thread simply places the syscall number in a conventionnal register determined by the OS developers and they call an instruction to jump into the kernel at a specific address that the kernel decides by writing a register at boot. Once there, the kernel looks at the register for the number and determines what driver to call based on the operation.

On Linux and some place else, it is done with files. You call syscalls on files and the OS has a driver attached to the file. They are called virtual files. A lot of transfer mechanisms are similar to the reading/writing files pattern so Linux uses that to make a general driver model where the kernel doesn't even need to understand the driver. The driver just says create me a file there that's not really on the hard disk and if someone opens it and calls an operation on it then call this function that's there in my driver. From there, the driver can do whatever it wants because it is in kernel mode. It just creates the proper data structures in DRAM and writes the registers of the device it drives to make it do something.